# git ls-files excluding files from .myignorefile

Tags: git, grep

I want to get all files from a repository but ignoring files that are not listed or don't match in the .gitignore file using regular expressions or some kind of options such as "exclude-from=.myignorefile".

Let's say these are my files after I do `git ls-files`:

- .gitignore
- index.html
- assets/app.less
- assets/app.css
- assets/app.js

But I don't want the `assets/app.less` and `.gitignore` files to be shown. Is there any option to accomplish this? I thought exclude-from was going to do the job but I misunderstood it:

```
Read exclude patterns from <file>; 1 per line.
```

Edit: I don't list those files in the .gitignore file because I want to track them but I don't want to use them for something else, lets say not uploading them to an ftp server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `git ls-files` can do this. But you can pipe its output to `grep` (or other) and exclude whatever you want, for example:

```
$ git ls-files | grep -v -e ^.gitignore -e ^assets/app.less
index.html
assets/app.css
assets/app.js
```